# Formfield should have 4 numbers followed by 2 letters in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I am writing an application where a user could fill in their zipcode. In the Netherlands a zipcode has a format of 4 times a number, followed by 2 letters. For example, 1234AB.

In my test I have written so far:

```
before(:each) do
  @zipcode = Zipcode.new
  @zipcode.zipcode = "1234AB"
  @zipcode.house_number = 2
end

it "should have a valid zipcode" do
  @zipcode.zipcode.should_not be_empty
  @zipcode.zipcode.should be_a(String)
  @zipcode.zipcode.length.should == 6
end
```

How ca I write the test that it checks if there are 4 numbers followed by 2 letters? And how should I write that in code it self?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use a [Regex](http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/regexes/) (regular expression). For your example, it would be quite simple:

```
/\A[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{2}\z/
```

which means: *Line start, 4 times a digit, 2 times a uppercase letter, line end.*

(I know this might not look simple if you're not familiar with the concept, but just read up on it and it will become clear very quickly. I recommend to read up on regexes in a Ruby context to know about all the quirks of Ruby regular expressions if you don't already.)

---

To use this regex inside your spec, I think you can use the following:

```
@zipcode.zipcode.should match(/\A[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{2}\z/)
```

To use it to actually validate this format inside your model, use [this](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates):

```
validates :zipcode, format: /\A[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{2}\z/
```

Comment: Thanks! I've only used regexes for validating emails but never thought it could count the number of digits for example.