# Java Regex : 4 Letters followed by 2 Integers

Tags: java, regex, string

Regex beginner here.

Already visited the followings, none answers my question :

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296056/regex-for-2-letters-followed-by-4-digits), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925837/2-random-letters-followed-by-4-digits), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547937/formfield-should-have-4-numbers-followed-by-2-letters-in-rspec), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32811232/regex-for-a-6-character-long-string-that-consists-of-four-letters-followed-by-2), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30784013/one-or-two-letters-followed-by-3-4-numbers), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439666/regex-pattern-any-two-letters-followed-by-six-numbers), etc.

I have a simple regex to check if a string contains 4 chars followed by 2 digits.

```
[A-Za-z]{4}[0-9]{2}
```

But, when using it, it doesn't matches. Here is the method I use and an example of input and output :

### Input in a JPasswordField

```
Mypass85
```

### Output

```
false
```

### Method

```
public static boolean checkPass(char[] ca){
    String s = new String(ca);
    System.out.println(s); // Prints : Mypass85
    p = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z]{4}[0-9]{2}");
    return p.matcher(s).matches();
}
```

Comment: Why would `"Mypass85"`, 6 letters followed by 2 numbers, match a pattern that expects 4 letters followed by 2 numbers?

Comment: Think that `"[A-Za-z]{4,}[0-9]{2,}"` will do the trick since your pattern actually is 4+ char followed by 2+ digits

Comment: @rgettman Oh my I feel stupid. :( Thank you very much. Answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Maybe also you need declairation: `Pattern p = ...`

Comment: @hata pattern is actually a class instance but thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promoting a comment to an answer.

It doesn't match because `"Mypass85"` is 6 letters followed by 2 numbers, but your pattern expects exactly 4 letters followed by 2 numbers.

You can either pass something like `"Pass85"` to match your existing pattern, or you can get `"Mypass85"` to match by changing the `{4}` to `{6}` or to `{4,}` (4 or more).

Comment: Thanks again for the help. Sometimes the little things that makes your brain explode lol.

Comment: @YassinHajaj We've all been there.  Sometimes all it takes is someone new to the problem, with a fresh view.

Answer (score 3):

`Matcher#matches` attempts to match full input. Use `Matcher#find` instead:

```
public static boolean checkPass(String s){
    System.out.println(s); // Prints : Mypass85
    p = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z]{4}[0-9]{2}");
    return p.matcher(s).find();
}
```

Comment: It works in my test and returns `true` for `Mypass85`

Comment: Ok, I edited my question. I'm actually receiving a char array from a JPasswordField but did not think it was important.

Comment: Eventually this method gets a string so it won't matter from what source this `String` is coming. Can you use `System.out.printf("[%s] ", s);` to print it and see what you get.

Comment: Thanks again but the problem was with the number of characters to find. Input : 6-2 and my Regex checked for 4-2 :s Changed it to "[A-Za-z]{6}[0-9]{2}" and it works now

Comment: But your question started with this **I have a simple regex to check if a string contains 4 chars followed by 2 digits**

Comment: sorry I'm really tired I think. just tried it again and works. Upvote.